# Is the Lagrangian in the Standard Model exact or approximate?

Tags: particle-physics, lagrangian-formalism, standard-model, quarks, gauge-invariance

We say that the Standard Model has $SU(3)_{C} \otimes SU(2)_{L} \otimes U(1)_{Y}$ symmetries. However, the $SU(2)_{L}$ symmetry of the doublet ($u, d$) is not exact because $u$ and $d$ have different masses. Does this imply that the Standard Model Lagrangian is not precise because it treats ($u, d$) as though it has an exact $SU(2)$ symmetry? Furthermore, if treating ($u ,d$) as an $SU(2)$ doublet makes the Lagrangian imprecise, can we treat $u$ and $d$ separately so as to develop a more precise Lagrangian?

Answer (score 11):

You seem to be mixing up a few different things. The Standard Model does *not* say the up and down quark must have the same mass.

- The up and down quark form a doublet of the flavor symmetry $SU(2)_F$. This is an approximate symmetry that is broken explicitly by the up and down quark mass difference.
- The *left-handed* up and down quarks form a doublet $Q_L$ of weak isospin $SU(2)_L$. This is a factor of the Standard Model gauge group.
- The right-handed up and down quarks form two singlets $U_R$ and $D_R$ of weak isospin $SU(2)_L$.
- The gauge symmetry of the Standard Model does place restrictions on the masses of the quarks; namely it requires them to all be *zero*. The quarks instead acquire masses through the Higgs mechanism, which breaks electroweak symmetry.
- There is no requirement for the up quark and down quark to get the same mass, because their masses come from independent Yukawa couplings, namely $H Q_L U_R$ and $H Q_L D_R$.

You've asked almost ten questions about $SU(2)_F$ and $SU(2)_L$, and I really recommend just picking up any book on the Standard Model and reading through it.

Answer (score 2):

The standard model Lagrangian does not model quantum gravity nor dark matter (as far as we know), hence it is certainly not an 'exact' description of the universe *anyway*.

However, your question is with regards to the SU(2) symmetry in the standard model Lagrangian. In this respect, there is no loss of precision as far as I know when one treats the SU(2) doublets on the same footing because it is a *spontaneously broken symmetry* and spontaneous symmetry breaking need not be put into the Lagrangian by hand.

As a simple example, in the Ising spin model of Ferromagnetism, a spin can either point up or it can point down and the up and down spin configurations are treated on an equal footing and this is manifest as a symmetry of the system, even though in the low-temperature regime the system will spontaneously choose a preferred spin direction and form a Ferromagnet.